# What, if any, is the name of a k-uniform hypergraph where edges are ordered tuples

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

Suppose I have a hypergraph where the set of vertices can be partitioned into n subsets with n < k, and edges in this graph are restricted to ordered tuples having some structure imposed relating to the partitions. For example, if n = 2 and k = 4 edges may be constrained to those of the form (a, b, c, d) where a and d are from the same partition and b and c are from the same partition but a and b (and consequently c and d) are in different partitions. Is there a name for this type of structure? Can the particular case given be considered an extension of a bipartite graph?